# How to Create/Edit a text file (.rtf) for Mac Osx in fireMonkey Rad studio XE2?

Tags: macos, delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I have created a Fire Monkey HD app in Rad Studio xe2.I have created text file for windows in my application using `AssignFile()` method.Now I want to create text file for MAC OSx.How can I do it??

Comment: `AssignFile` is soooo last century. It'll give you issues with Unicode. I'll put a reminder in my agenda to enter a QC wish to mark it as deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

Delphi includes the [`System.IOUtils.TFile`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.IOUtils.TFile) this is a record containing methods used to perform various operations on files, So to create a text file you can use  the [TFile.WriteAllText](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.IOUtils.TFile.WriteAllText)  passing the content of the file directly or use the [`TFile.Create`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.IOUtils.TFile.Create) method that create a file and return a `TFileStream`. Also you can use the [`TFileStream`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Classes.TFileStream) class directly.

All the above methods works in Windows and OSX.

Answer (score 2):

AssignFile is a seriously outdated function.

In modern (and cross platform) apps you should be using streams.